# How can I tell if I have viewed a Comment (or it's Card) in my list of Notifciations in Trello?

Tags: trello

In Trello, I see a list of Notifications on the right with a red alarm "bell" to signify I have new notifications ( @comments to me, etc.)

But, I can't tell which of them I've *already* viewed.

One possible solution:

A card that has a Notification since I last looked at that card will show the notifcation (red alarm bell) icon.
But, I see no way to search on those cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the red alarm "bell" you should see a list of new notifications.  Look for the darker side bar on the left side of each notice in the list.  Trello clears this bar when you close the notification list.
Click the bell again to see the difference.

Notes:

- Trello keeps track of what notices or cards you open but can't tell what notices you read.
- Look for the link ".. X more notifications.." to open a larger list of notices.
- When you have read all notifications the "bell" changes to the normal ""no new notifications" color